# Can started and bound services live "forever"?

Tags: android, android-service

I understand that a service can run in two modes, started and bound.

What I don't quite understand from the developer docs or other questions on this site, is whether a service running as both started and bound will exit when the last component unbinds from it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> whether a service running as both started and bound will exit when the last component unbinds from it?

If something called `startService()` on the `Service`, it will remain running, regardless of what `bindService()` and `unbindService()` calls may have gone on. Eventually, Android will stop the service, or the user will kill the service, but neither will happen immediately upon the last `unbindService()`.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! So services are elegible for the same kind of garbage collection as activities and can't be guaranteed to always run?

Comment: @rogerkk: Absolutely. An "everlasting service" is an anti-pattern in Android in most cases. Remember that many Android devices have limited RAM. Too many developers have been "leaking" services, and so users and the OS has been more aggressive about getting rid of them. Most situations where you'd want a service to run forever are better candidates for use with `AlarmManager` -- think `cron` jobs vs. always-running daemons in OS X or Linux, for example.

Comment: Thanks again! Appreciate always getting great answers from you. :)